# Simplify Redundant JS/JQuery Functions for Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of the same functions happening in my custom JS page and was wondering what is the best way to simply this code and less redundant. (DRY?)

I am still very new to JS/Javascript and hoping to improve the way the navigation works throughout various sections I will be adding to this webpage.

```
;(function () {

'use strict';



// iPad and iPod detection
var isiPad = function(){
    return (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1);
};

var isiPhone = function(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
};

// Parallax
var parallax = function() {
    $(window).stellar();
};



// Burger Menu
var burgerMenu = function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.js-mi-nav-toggle', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( $('#navbar').is(':visible') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }



    });

};


var goToTop = function() {

    $('.js-gotop').on('click', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });

};


// Page Nav
var clickMenu = function() {

    $('#navbar a:not([class="external"])').click(function(event){
        var section = $(this).data('nav-section'),
            navbar = $('#navbar');

            if ( $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length ) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top
                }, 500);
           }

        if ( navbar.is(':visible')) {
            navbar.removeClass('in');
            navbar.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            $('.js-mi-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });


};

// Reflect scrolling in navigation
var navActive = function(section) {

    var $el = $('#navbar > ul');
    $el.find('li').removeClass('active');
    $el.each(function(){
        $(this).find('a[data-nav-section="'+section+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
    });

};

var navigationSection = function() {

    var $section = $('section[data-section]');

    $section.waypoint(function(direction) {

        if (direction === 'down') {
            navActive($(this.element).data('section'));
        }
    }, {
        offset: '150px'
    });

    $section.waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'up') {
            navActive($(this.element).data('section'));
        }
    }, {
        offset: function() { return -$(this.element).height() + 155; }
    });

};





// Window Scroll
var windowScroll = function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){

        var header = $('#mi-header'),
            scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ( scrlTop > 500 && scrlTop <= 2000 ) {
            header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top mi-animated slideInDown');
        } else if ( scrlTop <= 500) {
            if ( header.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top') ) {
                header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top mi-animated slideOutUp');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    header.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top mi-animated slideInDown slideOutUp');
                }, 100 );
            }
        }

    });
};



// Animations
// Home

var homeAnimate = function() {
    if ( $('#mi-home').length > 0 ) {

        $('#mi-home').waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#mi-home .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);


                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var introAnimate = function() {
    var intro = $('#mi-intro');
    if ( intro.length > 0 ) {

        intro.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

                var sec = intro.find('.to-animate').length,
                    sec = parseInt((sec * 200) + 400);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    intro.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    intro.find('.to-animate-2').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('bounceIn animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, sec);



                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var infoAnimate = function() {
    var info = $('#mi-info');
    if ( info.length > 0 ) {

        info.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    info.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);



                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var discussAnimate = function() {
    var info = $('#mi-discuss');
    if ( info.length > 0 ) {

        info.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    info.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);



                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var tutorialsAnimate = function() {
    if ( $('#mi-videos').length > 0 ) {

        $('#mi-videos').waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#mi-videos .to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);


                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var examplesAnimate = function() {
    var info = $('#mi-examples');
    if ( info.length > 0 ) {

        info.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    info.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);



                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};


var businessAnimate = function() {
    var business = $('#mi-business');
    if ( business.length > 0 ) {

        business.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

                var sec = business.find('.to-animate').length,
                    sec = parseInt((sec * 200) - 400);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    business.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    business.find('.to-animate-2').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInDown animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, sec);


                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};

var contactAnimate = function() {
    var contact = $('#mi-contact');
    if ( contact.length > 0 ) {

        contact.waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    contact.find('.to-animate').each(function( k ) {
                        var el = $(this);

                        setTimeout ( function () {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );

                    });
                }, 200);

                $(this.element).addClass('animated');

            }
        } , { offset: '80%' } );

    }
};


// Document on load.
$(function(){

    parallax();

    burgerMenu();

    clickMenu();

    windowScroll();

    navigationSection();

    goToTop();


    // Animations
    homeAnimate();
    introAnimate();
    infoAnimate();
    discussAnimate();
    tutorialsAnimate();
    examplesAnimate();
    businessAnimate();
    contactAnimate();


});


}());
```

Thank you!

Comment: Start with one redundant thing, make it one/once occurrence in code and work from there?  My scroll broke my eyes on all that vertical white space (blank lines) you have there.

Comment: Another approach is to start with : split your functions to smaller functions until they do one and only one thing. When you achieve to do this, you will find very easily the redondant parts and you will be able to reuse parts of code

Answer (score 0):

For an example, take two functions you have, make them into one by passing object i.e.

OLD stuff:

```
var discussAnimate = function() {
  var info = $('#mi-discuss');
  if (info.length > 0) {
    info.waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          info.find('.to-animate').each(function(k) {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
            }, k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo');
          });
        }, 200);
        $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      }
    }, {
      offset: '80%'
    });
  }
};

var tutorialsAnimate = function() {
  if ($('#mi-videos').length > 0) {
    $('#mi-videos').waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#mi-videos .to-animate').each(function(k) {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
            }, k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo');
          });
        }, 200);
        $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      }
    }, {
      offset: '80%'
    });
  }
};
```

NEW stuff - note I did NOT focus on WHAT it does, which I would do differently but more on your question:

```
var thingAnimate = function(mything) {
  var myT = mything;// just here to make it obvious
  if (!!myT.length) {
    myT.waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          myT.find('.to-animate').each(function(k) {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              el.addClass('fadeInUp animated');
            }, k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo');
          });
        }, 200);
        $(this.element).addClass('animated');
      }
    }, {
      offset: '80%'
    });
  }
};
thingAnimate($('#mi-videos'));
thingAnimate($('#mi-discuss'));
```

The nested timeouts seem like code smell to me here but that is not your question.

Look for other things:
See here you toggle a class right?

```
if ( $('#navbar').is(':visible') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Seems like someone might have thought of that...so a bit of research on your part finds: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Thus:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active', $('#navbar').is(':visible'));
```